# Treat String as Hex Python

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, hex

How can I treat a string which is a hexadecimal number as a hexadecimal number? For example, I am loading in a file of hexadecimal numbers but Python is loading the file in as a string. Is it possible to get Python to treat the hexadecimal numbers in the file as hexadecimal numbers? I'm using Python 2.7

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `int`, specifying base-16:

```
>>> int('FFABCD', 16)
16755661
```

*Edit in reply to comment:*
OK, misunderstood.

```
>>> hex(int('0061', 16))
'0x61'
```

Works I suppose, but I won't be surprised if someone responds with a simpler way.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! But the problem is, I have a number that is already a hexadecimal number, for example 0061, but currently it's being treated like a string but I would like Python to realise it's a hexadecimal number already. When I use the int() function it changes to 97, but I need the number to stay as it is because it's already hexadecimal, Python just thinks it's a string.

Comment: @user3452305: Use `int` if you need a number. The string representation is in base 10, but it isn't a "decimal number" or a "hexadecimal number". `hex` converts a number to a string that's a hexadecimal literal.

Comment: @user3452305: I wonder if maybe your file is a byte string that has been hex encoded, e.g. `codecs.encode(b'\x00\x61', 'hex_codec') == b'0061'`. In that case you'd open the file as `f = codecs.open(filename, encoding='hex_codec')`.