# Treat String as Hex and keeping format

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a similar questions as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22596537/treat-string-as-hex-python) one: I have strings which contain hex values such as `"0x8F"` which I need to convert to hex. Using the previous answer and doing

```
int("0x8F", 16)
```

works, but the result is displayed as a regular int (143 in the example).

Is it possible to keep the format as hex after conversion??

Comment: Are you trying to output them as hex? just go print(hex(intVal)) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2269827/how-to-convert-an-int-to-a-hex-string

Comment: What does is it mean "keep the format as hex"? If it means "keep the original string", well, you already have it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert an int to a hex string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2269827/how-to-convert-an-int-to-a-hex-string)

Comment: @silent when I say you already have the string I mean you can just keep it and output it when you need to. No need for extra code. Use the integer representation where needed (comparisons etc.) and the string representation where needed (printing).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `format` to get hex formatting of a number. Check out the docs for format [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#format).

This will print out the value you want:

```py
print(format(143, '#X'))
```